# What are the best resources for Crystallography?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, material-science, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

I am undertaking a module in nanosurfaces and I was unaware that I would require some knowledge in Crystallography. The information that I must know regarding this area are *Miller indices, Symmetries, Bracket conventions*, so that I can answer some example questions such as:

- sketch for a face-centred cubic structure the (100), (110) and (111) planes and identify their in-plane symmetries
- draw the (0001) plane of a hexagonal structure with the principal in-plane directions of type <1-100> and <-2110>;
- sketch the (210) plane of a simple cubic structure and calculate its angle to the (100) plane? Remind yourself of the Ewald sphere construction for reciprocal space and diffraction.

**What are the best sources of information for Crystallography? What books would you recommend?**
I have come across books such as :

- *The basics of crystallography and diffraction* by C. Hammond ;
- *Fundamentals of Crystallography* by Carmelo Giacovazzo;
- *Crystallography made crystal clear* by Gale Rhodes.

Would any of these be good for the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

I personally used [*The basics of crystallography and diffraction*](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198738671.001.0001) by C. Hammond in conjunction with my material science class and the book did a more than outstanding job in explaining the basic concepts that you would like to know.